# how to display data in custom table in a form view (Odoo)

Tags: treeview, odoo

I want to make some calculations with product data and display them in a custom table.

Specifically what I want to do is:
1. take a list of products of a particular invoice
2. calculate the percentage of the product price to the total value of the invoice
3. display the custom table with the name of the product and the calculated value

for example:
 I have a list of the kind:

```
[{'name': u'Ipad', 'percentage': 45},
{'name': u'Imac', 'percentage': 20}]
```

How I can display the result in a notebook page  of form view?  Maybe I can do this with Qweb templates?, any example?, thanks.

Comment: Most likely you would need to use a computed field, but you would need to be more specific.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, specifically what I want to do is take a list of products of a particular invoice, calculate the percentage of the product price to the total value of the invoice, and display the custom table with the name of the product and the calculated value, for example , I have a list of the kind: [{'name': u'Ipad', 'percentage': 45}, {'nombre': u'Imac', 'percentage': 20}], how I can display the result in a tree view, thanks